# Python 3.6 Mac OS X - How do you get PIP install?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pip

In various educational guides, I have been guided to install Python modules with an easy one-line command entered in the terminal: **pip install whatever**

Well, when I type "pip install" it is not found.

Elsewhere in Stack Overflow the following instructions have been given:

- Use apt-get -- but I am not using linux
- Use easy-install pip -- but
  it also produces command not found.
- Use easy-install3 pip -- same problem: command not found.

Does PIP not install when you install Python 3.6?
Do I really have to edit the path myself - it seems to me, if necessary, the developers who created the installer would have done this and the path would have been updated when Python was installed.

Poking around the hidden system folders in OS X, I see that **there is an alias called pip3.6 in usr/local/bin** that was created a week ago when I installed Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

I would try:

```
pip3.6 install whatever
```

Comment: Yep thanks Penguin Brian, I just happened to try that after posting. That works.

Answer (score 1):

Right, worked it out now.

Pip is installed when Python 3.6 is installed - but instead of typing "pip install", you type:

```
pip3.6 install <ModuleYouWant>
```

I guess this is so people can run Python 2.7 and 3.6 simultaneously.. it'd be nice if it were a little more intuitive though, or there were some instructions, or it just worked as pip gave you the option "2.7 or 3.6?"

For those OS X users in the dark like I was, please note that system files like the usr folder can be seen in Finder if you press **Command+Shift+G** then in the dialog box that pops up type **/usr** (There are other ways to see hidden folders too).